# Which browsers (and versions) support callback arguments for setTimeout and setInterval?

Tags: javascript

According to [**WHATWG**](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers) and [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout), `window.setTimeout` and `window.setInterval` have the form

```
var handle = window.setTimeout( handler [, timeout [, arguments... ] ] );
var handle = window.setInterval( handler [, timeout [, arguments... ] ] );
```

Most sources say (generic) Internet Explorer doesn't support the optional `arguments`.
Is there a list of browsers and versions that do and do not support it?

An example of the way to test for support would be

```
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
setTimeout: <span id="t">testing..</span><br/>
setInterval: <span id="i">testing..</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
t = window.setTimeout( // setTimeout
    function (b) { // callback
        document.getElementById('t').innerHTML = (b || false); // test for arg1
    },
    0,
    true // arg1
);
i = window.setInterval( // setInterval
    function (b) { // callback
        document.getElementById('i').innerHTML = (b || false); // test for arg1
        window.clearInterval(i);
    },
    0,
    true // arg1
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

With expected result `true` and result on failure as `false`.

Comment: Since it is so easy to simply use an anonymous function to pass extra arguments *and* it runs everywhere, why not just use that and avoid the headaches?

Comment: It is a question I couldn't find an actual answer to anywhere, as in, the answers assumed every version of each browser is the same, so I went to find out and decided to share.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a test based upon the example code in the question and [**BrowserShots**](http://browsershots.org/) for the browsers, here is a table of browser support

```
Browser  Version  setTimeout  setInterval
Chrome     4+      true        true         Lowest version testable
Firefox    3+      true        true         Did not test lower versions
MSIE       6       false       false
MSIE       7       false       false
MSIE       8       false       false
MSIE       9       false       false
MSIE      10       true        true
Opera                                       Not tested
```